# Escape markdown link marker to use it as normal text

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I have a short R error message that I am documenting in RStudio as markdown document (*.md).

It looks like a markdown link so it is misinterpreted and formatted like a link.

How can I prevent that (keeping it formatted as normal text)?

Example:

```
Error in value [[3L]](cond) : unused argument (cond)
```

is rendered as

[image]

My current work-around is backticking but this changes the format into code style:

```
Error in value `[[3L]](cond)` : unused argument (cond)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `\` to escape the part in parathenses.

```
Error in value [[3L]]\(cond) : unused argument (cond)
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: That easy ;-) I thought there is a starting and ending tag for that but escaping seems to work for all markers (eg. `\-` to prevent unnumbered enumerations...). THX :-)